# AngularJS: unable to access scope variable after ng-repeat in view

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I have created an Angular JS script for tabs and trying to access a scope variable below in View. But, no success.
Tab click is working fine, but unable to print selectedIndex variable later. Please help.

**This is the Code in my View:**

```
<nav id="App1" ng-app="navTab" ng-controller="NavTabController">
  <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'selected-class-name':$index == selectedIndex}" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">{{item.product_name}}</a>
</nav>
{{selectedIndex}}
```

**And here is the Angular Script:**

```
<script>
  var navTabModule = angular.module("navTab", [])
  navTabModule.controller("NavTabController", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {product_name: "dashboard"},
      {product_name: "contacts"},
      {product_name: "appointments"},
      {product_name: "todos"},
      {product_name: "transactions"},
      {product_name: "items"},
      {product_name: "calendar"},
      {product_name: "users"},
      {product_name: "reports"}
    ];
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    $scope.itemClicked = function($index){
      $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the variable **outside** of the scope, after the `nav` element.

Put the binding **inside** the scope, or move the controller to an outer element (make the scope broader), and it will work:

```
<nav id="App1" ng-app="navTab" ng-controller="NavTabController">
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'selected-class-name':$index == selectedIndex}" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">{{item.product_name}}</a>
    {{selectedIndex}}
</nav>
```

or

```
<div ng-app="navTab" ng-controller="NavTabController">
    <nav id="App1">
        <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'selected-class-name':$index == selectedIndex}" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">{{item.product_name}}</a>
    </nav>
    {{selectedIndex}}
</div>
```